# Reference request: definition of class

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, foundations

I am looking for a reference on mathematically strict definition of class. For example, how do you construct the class of all ZFC-sets?

Comment: See [Classes in $\mathsf {NBG}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Classes_in_set_theory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within ZFC set theory, "class" is not a technical concept, so you won't find a definition of it.

It is common to use the word "class" to speak about all the sets that satisfy some particular property, as a collective, *without* implying that there is a *set* that has exactly those sets as elements. But -- at least from the point of view of the ZFC formalism -- this is an *informal* usage that doesn't correspond to anything in the theory.

When we're speaking *about* ZFC, seen from the outside, it is common to use the word "class" to speak about the collection of individuals of a model of ZFC that satisfy some particular *formula*. The formula can usually have parameters from the model, but this depends on exactly who is speaking and in which context. For example for the formula $x=x$ you get the class of *all* individuals in the model.

This usage is sometimes also imitated when we're speaking about ZFC purely as a syntactic proof system without any model in mind. In that case, however, a "class" is neither more nor less than a *formula* in the language of set theory, and speaking about it as a *thing* is just a suggestive shorthand without technical content.

---

There are other set theories where classes do have a formal existence -- for example NBG set theory. But that won't give you a *definition* of "class" because in NBG, "class" is a fundamental, primitive concept -- A class is whatever behaves like the NBG axioms say classes behave.